# Matching occurrence in string with regex for value replacement?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've spent some time on this problem but really need help from a regex guru.

So far I have the following which doesn't quite give me what I need.

[.*?]\s[=><]+\s[@]\w+

From the following sample string, I need all occurrences of a field followed by a parameter\variable. A parameter starts with an '@'.

I am then going to use the result to replace the contents of each value in .net.

Therefore, the regex expression would match

```
[System.TeamProject] = @project
[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] >= @startOfDay
[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] >= @startOfDay
```

Note [System.State] = 'Closed' is not matched.

Sample string

```
select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] from WorkItems where [System.TeamProject] = @project and [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] >= @startOfDay and [System.State] = 'Closed' and [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] >= @startOfDay
```

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Change the square brackets of the character  class `[.*?]` to a group `(.*?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do what you want:

```
\[([^]]*)]\s+[><=]+\s+(\@\w+)
```

The main change is that the `[` and `]` in the initial part of your regex needed to be escaped. I have also added capture groups to collect the field name (group 1) and parameter value (group 2).

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ou5ruY/2)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe you're trying to write some similar expression to:

```
\[([^\]]*)\]\s*(=|>=|<=)\s*(@\w+)
```

and replace with some string similar to:

```
[new_value] $2 $3
```

I've added some capturing groups, wasn't sure about the desired output, you can simply remove or modify those if/as you wish.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T8Hz0W/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\[([^\]]*)\]\s*(=|>=|<=)\s*(@\w+)";
        string substitution = @"[new_value] $2 $3";
        string input = @"select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] from WorkItems where [System.TeamProject] = @project and [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] >= @startOfDay and [System.State] = 'Closed' and [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] >= @startOfDay

Note [System.State] = 'Closed' is not matched.";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/T8Hz0W/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/T8Hz0W/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]